# How do I repeat an action in c# to fix the jumping mechanism

Tags: loops, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

I'm creating a basic 2D platformer game however the jumping mechanism will only run once and land directly afterwards. How do I loop this?

I tried detection collisions (from tag: Terrain) and this does help a lot however it's still not working correctly.

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb2D;

    private Vector2 velocity;

    Vector2 xvelocity = new Vector2(10, 0);
    Vector2 yvelocity = new Vector2(0, 10);

    public float jumptime;
    bool grounded = true;

    bool jump = false;

    void Start()
    {
        rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            jump = true;
        }

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Debug.Log(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        if (left == true)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Left");
            rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + -xvelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }

        if (right == true)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Right"); 
            rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + xvelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }

        //if (jump == true && grounded == true)
        //{
        //    jumptime -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        //    if (jumptime > 0)
        //    {
        //        rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + yvelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        //    }
        //    if (jumptime <= 0)
        //    {
        //        jump = false;
        //        jumptime = 2;
        //    }

        if (jump == true && grounded == true && jumptime > 0)
        {
            jumptime -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + yvelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        } else if (jumptime <= 0)
        {
            jump = false;
            jumptime = 2f;
        }

        //if (Time.fixedDeltaTime >= 2)
        //{
        //    jump = false;
        //    rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + -yvelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        //}
    }

    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("No longer in contact with " + other.transform.name);
        jump = true;
        grounded = false;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Terrain")
        {
            Debug.Log("Landed");
            jump = false;
            grounded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The expected outcome is that the action 'jump' will loop for ~1/1.5 seconds with a good height (vector2 yvelocity) so it will jump higher and will come down afterwards (thanks to the gravity from the Rigidbody (2D))

Comment: Look at your code and figure out what happens when `(jump == true && grounded == false && jumptime > 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments I think the main issue is coming from this line of code.

```
if (jump == true && grounded == true && jumptime > 0)
```

It is much likely that one of those bool is not what you expect it to be. Anyway I suggest you to convert the line like so:

```
if (jump && grounded && jumptime > 0)
```

You do not need == true for booleans.

Anyway, to solve your question in an easier way, I would suggest you to use AddForce instead of move (because you're using a rigibody2d anyway).

```
rb2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

A small note about horizontal velocity. If you're using a rigibody it would be better to move it with the same rigidbody and not with the transform:

```
rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + Vector2.left * xspeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

Your code will become:

```cs
public class PlayerController2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb2D;

    private Vector2 velocity;

    public float jumpForce = 5;
    bool grounded = true;

    void Start() { rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump") && grounded)
            rb2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

        //calculate horizontal speed here
        xspeed = ...;

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + Vector2.left * xspeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("No longer in contact with " + other.transform.name);
        grounded = false;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Terrain")
        {
            Debug.Log("Landed");
            grounded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, I checked the code and it worked however the charachter is floating when moving in the air.

Comment: EDIT: ``transform.position -= Vector3.left * xspeed * Time.deltaTime;`` fixed it.

Comment: That most likely depends on how you're handling horizontal movement (I cannot see the code in the question). Maybe you were not checking the horizontal speed if player was not on the ground. Anyway I added it to the code.

Comment: Last not it would be better to move the rigibody with the same rigidboty (also for horizontal movement) and not with the transform. All notes added to the code in the answer.

Comment: I used ``rb2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);`` for jumping and ``transform.position += Vector3.left * xspeed * Time.deltaTime;`` for left and right and that works perfectly.